# How to check yiiframework first time login user

Tags: php, yii, authentication

I'm currently busy with a project that needs users when they log in for the first time (and haven't created one yet). Honestly, I don't know where to start. I would like to do it in a good way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field in table
named last_login and update it on every login .

and if it is empty then sure it will be its first time :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a field in database `first_time_login`. If `first_time_login` is NULL or empty add current time .

As when new user is created `first_time_login` field will be empty. When user will login 1st time current time will be updated in `first_time_login` field with checking if field is not empty.